# What is the preferred way for handling missing member of DynamicObject?

Tags: c#, dynamic, exception

Usually when you override/implement a `bool TryDoSomething(...)` method you return `false` if it didn't work.

In case of the `DynamicObject` we return `false` and it throws an exception that just contains a generic error message.

For

```
public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
```

it would be

> Cannot invoke a non-delegate type

and that's it. There's neither any information which member didn't work nor what the parameters were.

To *improve* this I would just throw my own exception instead of returning `false` because it is going to fail anyway.

```
public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
{
    // ...
    throw new Exception($"Method '{binder.Name}' not found.");
    // ...
}
```

Is this the *only/best* way to do it or is there already something else?

This is somehow breaking the `TryDoSomething` pattern but on the other side it will fail anyway so why not? Will it break anything?

Comment: Thx for downvoting and not leaving any comment.

Comment: Seems like a fine question, odd that someone would feel otherwise. I'm partial to your solution as it seems simple enough for your to get the info you are after on exception.

Comment: Don't know well dynamic stuff but couldn't you use `InvokeMemberBinder.FallBackInvokeMember` somehow which last arg seems to contain data about the error (and use that to give a more explicit message) ?

Comment: @Sehnsucht it looks very promissing... but it's not trivial to use it... let me google first.

Comment: @Sehnsucht unfortunatelly this is only a return value for the [BindingHelper.Bind#L134](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Microsoft.CSharp/src/Microsoft/CSharp/RuntimeBinder/BinderHelper.cs#L134) in case the binding fails and at the same time for the [FallBackInvokeMember#L75](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Microsoft.CSharp/src/Microsoft/CSharp/RuntimeBinder/CSharpInvokeMemberBinder.cs#L75)

Answer (score 0):

The pattern for a "Try" method is to return a bool and swallow exceptions.

Perhaps it would be better to write your own wrapper around InvokeMember.  You should be able to create an extension method to handle this

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static object CustomInvokeMember(this Type t, string name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder,
        object target, object[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            return t.InvokeMember(name, invokeAttr, binder, target, args);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //TODO: parsing, custom handling, etc
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgive me if it's a stupid question but I don't really know how to apply this to  the overrides of the `DynamicObject` ;-(

Comment: Do you need to inject your code into the override (meaning some caller is already calling that method and you can't modify the caller)?

The caller expects the convention of the TryInvokeMember to NOT throw, so throwing is risky. If you have control of the calling code you can change the method or throw in the TryInvokeMember and handle the exception in the caller (but changing the method would be less confusing in the long run). 

TryInvokeMember returns an object in the out param. You could return the exception... The caller would have to test that as well so it is not a great solution.